# Trying to replicate COUNTIF in DAX to calculate a Measure in Pivot Table. I want to know which of SUMX or CALCULATE is more efficient?

Tags: excel, performance, excel-formula, dax, daxstudio

I want to calculate number of records on 'Data Dump' table where [Stage] column contains the value "Enquiry". I would also like to understand the difference in execution of these formulas.

I have used the below DAX formulas to evaluate - which formula is more efficient?

`=SUMX('Data Dump',MIN(SEARCH("Enquiry",'Data Dump'[Stage],,0),1))`

`=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Data Dump'),SEARCH("Enquiry",'Data Dump'[Stage],,0)>0)`

`=CALCULATE(COUNT('Data Dump'[Stage]),SEARCH("Enquiry",'Data Dump'[Stage],,0)>0)`

`=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(FILTER('Data Dump',SEARCH("Enquiry",'Data Dump'[Stage],,0)>0)))`

Also, would it be more efficient if I simply add formula columns to my data source table with 1 and 0 for different criteria (eg. value is "Enquiry", "Pipeline", "Converted", etc) and then sum it up to get total count?

Below are the results obtained by running in DAX Studio, performance is similar as far as I can identify.

[image]

Comment: CALCULATE isn't doing anything extra in your last example. Given the similarity in performance, use whichever is most clean and intuitive for future maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend one of the following:

```
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'Data Dump' ),
    CONTAINSSTRING ( 'Data Dump'[Stage], "Enquiry" )
)
```

or

```
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        'Data Dump',
        CONTAINSSTRING ( 'Data Dump'[Stage], "Enquiry" )
    )
)
```

I'd expect these to be similar in efficiency but you'd need to actually test to know for sure.

Comment: Did not find CONTAINSSTRING in DAX Studio I downloaded for some reason, but turns out it uses the SEARCH function (https://dax.guide/containsstring/).

Comment: I have updated the DAX Studio screenshot, do let me know if there is any distinction. I cannot figure out the meaning of CPU and Parallelism metrics - can you shed some light on it?

Comment: If I'm interpreting your screenshot correctly, the non-SUMX queries are all being interpreted identically (I think what I suggested would match too). They're all fast enough in this test that I don't see a meaningful distinction between them.